# RegularExpressionValidator Expression needed

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

i am using asp.net 3.5 and VB.net, i need a validation expression to validate a string of 1 to 50 characters, white spaces, numbers, special character are all allowed, simply, it should match an nvarchar(50) database field.
it will be applied to a textbox, also, the same case but for 1-200 characters which will be validating a multi-line textbox..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that it just needs to ensure that there are between 1 and 50/200 characters in the strings?

If so, try these:

```
^[\s\S]{1,50}$
^[\s\S]{1,200}$
```

Testing for `[\s\S]` rather than `[.]` ensures that any newlines in the multiline textarea don't cause problems.

Comment: Yes, also i am accepting any character that can be stored in an nvarchar database field.